# Static method that returns a new instance?

Tags: java

I've been tasked to make this static method:
"createPerson – This method creates a new person given their first name, last, name, and age.  Then it returns a new instance of that person."

But since we just learned static methods I am confused.

Here's the driver class:

```
public class FriendlyPeople {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Let's meet some friendly people");
    Person[] people =
            {
                    new Person("Tom Jones", 29),
                    new Person("Bob Jones", 40),
                    new Person("Alf Pererdur", 10),
                    new Person("Ripley Carver",20),
                    new Person("Britton Raven",47),
                    new Person("Joyce Elihu",93),
                    new Person("Kevin Jody",63),
                    new Person("Ben Jayce", 32),
                    new Person("Emerson Ezra",27),
                    new Person("Yorick Fearghal",44),
                    new Person("Kim Yori",23),
                    new Person("Sheldon Ambrose", 36),
                    new Person("Leonard Damion",33),
                    new Person("Agam Saburou", 53),
                    new Person ("Webster Chaz", 46),
                    new Person("Carol Dudel", 31)
            };
    Person p1 = new Person("Dacre Casey", 29);
    System.out.println("Testing the initial person");
    System.out.println(p1.toString());
    System.out.println();


    System.out.println("Adding one friend");
    p1.addFriend(Person.createPerson("Wetzel Edmund", 62));
    p1.printFriends();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Adding a new friend using the overloaded operator");
    p1.addFriend("Judith Katheryne", 32);
    p1.printFriends();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Adding a group of friends that exceeds the number of friends.");
    p1.addFriends(people);
    p1.printFriends();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Removing a friend "+people[0].toString());
    p1.removeFriend(people[0]);
    p1.printFriends();
    System.out.println();


}
```

**Here's my code so far:**

```
public class Person {
private String name;
private int age;
private Person[] friends;

//Constructor for person
public Person(String name, int age)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
//Constructor array for person
public Person()
{
    this.friends = new Person[10];
}

//Accessors
public String getName() {return name;}

public int getAge() {return age;}

//Mutators
public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAge (int age)
{
    if (age < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("That is an invalid age");
        return;
    }
    this.age = age;
}

//Methods

public static String createPerson (String s)
{

}

public String toString() { return name + " " + age; }

public boolean equals (Person person) {
    return this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(person.getName()) && this.age == person.getAge();
}

//Add friend method
public void addFriend(Person person)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < friends.length; column++)
    {
        if (friends[0] != null || (friends[column] == null && friends[column-1] != null))
        {
            friends[column] = person;
        }
        if (friends[9] == person) {
            System.out.println("Friends list is full!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's the method I am trying to figure out in particular, It's probably simple:**

```
public static String createPerson (String s)
{

}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: The method being static shouldn't have anything to do with your confusion. Read the assignment - it's straightforward in telling you what to do...

Comment: Also according to the assignment, the `Person` should have *firstName* and *lastName* But you are having a single variable `name`

Comment: Is there any particular reason your set name and age are doing the same thing that you did in the constructor. I dont understand that. Is it so you can change the name without creating a new object?

Comment: Based on what your assignment says, the `createPerson` method should have 3 parameters, not one.

Answer (score 4):

At this point just note that static methods are not associated with an instantiated class. To call static methods:

```
    Person.createPerson("first", "last", 20);
```

Notice the call to the method the class name is used, not a variable referencing an object of the type Person. To create a method you use the word static as you did. From a static method, you cannot access non-static class fields of Person. Put your logic in static methods as you would other methods. 
Not judging any other code, the directions are telling you to do this:

```
    public static Person createPerson (String first, String last, int age)
    {
        return new Person(first, last, age);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are using a Factory (Static initializer), you should put the instance private.

Second, you should instantiate the friends list on both constructors, or you should use `this();` to get the other constructor (It's called overloading), but I advise you to use a ArrayList. If you don't know how to use it, use variable that tracks how many friend you have to use it as a pointer.

I advise you strongly to study the Collection Framework. The array List does the job you want very easily.

Third, if you are adding friends that already exist, you should get it from the list that you got. If it doesn't exist, you should add it to the list. I advise an HashMap, but an ArrayList will suffice. Here it it a remodulation of your code:

```java
public class FriendlyPeople {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Let's meet some friendly people");
        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Person[] peopleList = {
            Person.createPerson( "Tom Jones", 29),
            Person.createPerson( "Bob Jones", 40),
            Person.createPerson( "Alf Pererdur", 10),
            Person.createPerson( "Ripley Carver",20),
            Person.createPerson( "Britton Raven",47),
            Person.createPerson( "Joyce Elihu",93),
            Person.createPerson( "Kevin Jody",63),
            Person.createPerson( "Ben Jayce", 32),
            Person.createPerson( "Emerson Ezra",27),
            Person.createPerson( "Yorick Fearghal",44),
            Person.createPerson( "Kim Yori",23),
            Person.createPerson( "Sheldon Ambrose", 36),
            Person.createPerson( "Leonard Damion",33),
            Person.createPerson( "Agam Saburou", 53),
            Person.createPerson( "Webster Chaz", 46),
            Person.createPerson( "Carol Dudel", 31)
        };

        people.ensureCapacity( peopleList.length );

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < peopleList.length ; i++ ) {
            people.add( peopleList[i] );
        }

        Person p1 = Person.createPerson( "Dacre Casey", 29);
        people.add( p1 );
        System.out.println("Testing the initial person");
        System.out.println(p1.toString());
        System.out.println();


        System.out.println("Adding one friend");
        Person newPerson1 = Person.createPerson("Wetzel Edmund", 62);
        people.add( newPerson1 );
        p1.addFriend( newPerson1 );
        p1.printFriends();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Adding a new friend using the overloaded operator");
        Person newPerson2 = Person.createPerson( "Judith Katheryne", 32);
        people.add( newPerson2 );
        p1.addFriend( newPerson2 );
        p1.printFriends();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Adding a group of friends that exceeds the number of friends.");
        p1.addFriends(people);
        p1.printFriends();
        System.out.println();

        Person friendToRemove = people.get( 0 );
        //You don't need to explicit .toString
        System.out.println("Removing a friend "+friendToRemove);
        p1.removeFriend( friendToRemove );
        p1.printFriends();
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

And as for the `Person` class:

```java
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private ArrayList<Person> friends;

//Constructor for person
    private Person(String name, int age) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;

    }
//Constructor array for person
    private Person() {
        this.friends = new ArrayList<Person>(10);
    }
    //Accessors
    public String getName() {return name;}

    public int getAge() {return age;}

//Mutators
    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge (int age) {
        if (age < 0) {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid age");
            return;
        }
        this.age = age;
    }

//Methods

    @Override
    public String toString() { return name + " " + age; }

    public boolean equals (Person person) {
        return this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(person.getName()) && this.age == person.getAge();
    }

//Add friend method
    public void addFriend(Person person) {
        friends.add( person );
    }

    public void addFriends( ArrayList<Person> people ) {
        friends.addAll( people );
    }

    public void addFriends( Person[] people ) {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < people.length; i++ ) {
            Person friend = people[i];
            friends.add( friend );
        }
    }

    //To remove over an ArrayList I advice using an Iterator, but for now 
    //this is enought
    public void removeFriend(Person friend ) {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < friends.size(); i++ ) {
            Person person = friends.get( i );
            if( person.equals(friend) ){
                friends.remove( i );
            }
        }
    }

    public void printFriends() {
        System.out.println( "Friends: " );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < friends.size() ; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( friends.get( i ) );
        }
    }

    //I advise to leave static methods to the end. It leaves the code cleaner.
    public static Person createPerson ( String name, int age ) {
        return new Person( name, age );
    }

    public static Person createPerson () {
        return new Person();
    }
}
```

Once again, I advise you to study the Collection FrameWork. Yet, it is possible to do the thing without it. You could do what you wanted to do with a simple array, but then you should have used a variable to keep track of the number of friends (To work as a pointer.). When the pointer reaches the array length, just do this:

```java
private void increaseListLenght() {
    Person[] newFriendList = new Person[friends.lenght*1.75];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < friends.lenght ; i++ ) {
        newFriendList[i] = friends[i];
    }
    friends = newFriendList;
}
```

But if you choose to do this way, you can't have the list `final`.

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)